# I'm in a moving train filled with vacuum. I'm leaning to the rear wall, so the train pushes me forward. If I drop a ball, woudn't it hit my chest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, relative-motion

I'm assuming it has inertia, so no, it would continue to move forward and just fall to the the ground of the train. But has anyone really performed this experiment in a vacuum? In the absence of vacuum, for example, if the train is filled with air, wouldn't the air be the one that's pushing the ball forward? That would explain why the speed of light is always constant, because the speed of light is not affected by any medium, meaning it cannot be pushed by air for example.

I hope you believe in the saying: "there is no silly question!" :)

Answer (score 1):

> In the absence of vacuum, for example, if the train is filled with air, wouldn't the air be the one that's pushing the ball forward?

No.  We can, and have, tested that objects will keep the same velocity if no outside forces act upon them.  This is often referred to as Newtons First Law.

When the train has a vacuum inside and is moving at a constant velocity, everything inside the train should also be moving with that velocity.  If the train does have a constant velocity, the back wall of the is basically just propping you up so you don't fall.  Since you're already moving the same velocity as the train, you don't really need a force to push you forward, unless there is some other force pushing you backwards that you're trying to work against.

Also consider that the force of the air on the ball will be due to relative motion between the air and the ball (see [drag force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics))). This means that if the ball is moving the same speed as the air in the cabin, the air isn't applying any force to the ball, so replacing that air with a vacuum should have no effect on it's horizontal movement, and it should move horizontally the same in or outside of a vacuum.

Although no one has done your particular described experiment, other experiments would have shown consequences of this effect.  It probably wouldn't be *that* hard to test.  You would need a vacuum vessel of some sort (preferably clear so you can watch in real time), some way to launch the ball (like a spring mechanism you can control from outside the vessel), and a way to move the vessel at a constant speed.  I am quite certain that it will do as Newtonian physics predicts though, or else we would have run into many other contradictions already.

Comment: I believe the OP was asking for a pointer to an actual experiment rather than a statement of what we believe that experiment would show.

Comment: @WillO I was going to make a joke about how hard it would be to create a vacuum in a train cab; and how you're not likely to find someone willing to stand in it to throw a ball...  I guess I should mention that this conforms with experiments in vacuums, though it hasn't specifically been tested.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful information. I'm trying to get insights on why the speed of light is constant. It looks like it is not affected by the space around it, and it has not medium. So no matter what happens around it or how space is moving around it, or even on his path, its velocity is not slowed down by anything. I accept this fact, that life moves a constant speed no matter what. I just wanted to fully understand what in nature causes that. Or there is no causality for that? For example, there is causality for gravity, right? The graviton. What is the causality for light speed?